# redshift deletion on primary table using temp table is taking too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an ETL application where I read messages in 1k batches from a queue & do the following operations:

1. Parse the messages and create 20 CSV files for 20 different tables and gzip compress them
2. Copy these files to s3
3. Create temp tables and use Redshift S3 Copy
4. Compare master table for duplicates using the temp table and delete duplicates on master tables
5. Copy the rows on temp table to master table.

Everything was working fine until we noticed huge drop in the message processing throughput. On redshift console I see step 4 for certain tables are taking more than 10 mins now (these tables have billions rows now)

Is this expected behaviour?

i.e. when the table size grows, the dedup operations taking longer? Is there any other alternatives to this pattern?

EDIT: looks the size of the tables in question is in TB's (5.10 TB for one of the tables)

EDIT 2: I have put a where clause while performing step 4. Earlier this step used to scan billions of rows and TB's of data, now it has come down to a couple of thousands of rows and mb's of data. Also the time has reduced too.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have the heart to explain why - it's a lot of explaining, and I've done it many times, but there's no end of people operating Redshift incorrectly who need to know, but, yes, I can tell you, Redshift here is being operated incorrectly, and if operated correctly, you would not have the problems you have.  However, if operated correctly, you might not be able to use Redshift in the way you want to.  Sorry - but at least you do now know what you have isn't normal (although give usage here, it would be expected).

Comment: If you are frequently updating/deleting rows in a table (Step 4), the table will become unsorted and less-efficient to query. With billions of rows, it might not be adequately vacuumed to remove deleted rows and re-sort the data. See also: [Updating and inserting new data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html)

Comment: @MaxGanzII I'm not sure I follow your suggestions. Are you saying dedup check is not the right approach or this multi table set up itself is not the right way to do things on redshift?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein dedup operation is to prevent duplicates entries, on an ideal scenario there won't be duplicates, but there is no guarantee there won't be any duplicates. We are doing vaccum on a weekly basis.

Comment: Does your `WHERE` clause in the duplicate check match the SORTKEY on your big table? How are you doing that step -- are you using a `DELETE FROM big_table USING temp_table WHERE big_table.id = temp_table.id`, with the big table's SORT_KEY set to `id`?

Comment: I have a uuid as my distkey and a timestamp + some attribute name & value as sort key. My delete query would look like `delete from big table using temp_table where big_table.id = temp_table.id and big_table.attr_name = temp_table.attr_name and big_table.attr_val = temp_table.attr_val and big_table.created_date >= '<last 1 hour-in-timestamp>'`

Comment: The fields being used in that join do not match the SORTKEY, so Redshift would need to go through potentially millions or billions of rows to find matching rows. That is probably the cause of the slow-down. If most of your queries on the table normally use the SORTKEY, then that is the correct configuration. However, it also means that your de-duplication process will be extremely slow.

Comment: I'm afraid there are many things here which are incorrect for Redshift.  I'd have to explain a whole bunch of Redshift fundamentals to explain them all, and I've done it so many times for so many people, this isn't the way to help - I'm going to write a decent document about it, but that won't help you now.  With a bit of luck Bill will be along and willl help you out - he has a capability to keep going which I lack :-)  as it is John is helping out.